# HAProxy as a reverse proxy for backend already ssl enabled and SSL terminator for a backend exposed in port 80

Tags: ssl, reverse-proxy, haproxy, port-forwarding, certificate

I have 4 servers:

- proxy_server,
- $BK_SERVER_001,
- $BK_SERVER_002 and
- $BK_SERVER_003

The "proxy_server" only has an HAProxy enabled service with this configuration:
(please look at the rows marked as OPTION 1 & OPTION 2)

```
# StackOverflow
global
    log /dev/log    local0
    log /dev/log    local1 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon

    # Default SSL material locations
        ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
        crt-base /etc/ssl/private

    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
    ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3

defaults
        timeout connect 10s
        timeout client 30s
        timeout server 30s
    log global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull

# ***************** port 80 defs ************
frontend http_in
        mode http
        option httplog
        bind *:80       
        option forwardfor

        acl host_goose hdr(host) -i     www.example.edu
        redirect scheme https code 301 if !host_goose
        use_backend http_goose if host_goose

backend http_goose
        mode http
        server sonar $BK_SERVER_003:8080

# ***************** port 443 defs ************
frontend https_in
        mode tcp
        option tcplog

#       With this one, all works except sonar (OPTION 1)
#        bind *:443 

#       With this one, only works sonar (OPTION 2)
       bind *:443 ssl crt sonar.pem

        acl tls req.ssl_hello_type 1
        tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
        tcp-request content accept if tls

        acl host_server001 req.ssl_sni -i  opengrok.ci.example.edu
        acl host_server002 req.ssl_sni -i    gitlab.ci.example.edu
        acl host_server003 req.ssl_sni -i   jenkins.ci.example.edu
        acl host_server004 req.ssl_sni -i     nexus.ci.example.edu
        acl host_server005 req.ssl_sni -i   rancher.ci.example.edu
        acl host_server006 req.ssl_sni -i   reports.ci.example.edu
        acl host_server007 hdr(host) -i       sonar.ci.example.edu

        use_backend https_server001 if host_server001
        use_backend https_server002 if host_server002
        use_backend https_server003 if host_server003
        use_backend https_server004 if host_server004
        use_backend https_server005 if host_server005
        use_backend https_server006 if host_server006
        use_backend https_server007 if host_server007


#opengrok
backend https_server001
        mode tcp
        server server001 $BK_SERVER_001:28443
#gitlab
backend https_server002
        mode tcp
        server server002 $BK_SERVER_002:10443
#jenkins
backend https_server003
        mode tcp
        server server003 $BK_SERVER_001:7443
#nexus
backend https_server004
        mode tcp
        server server004 $BK_SERVER_001:8443
#rancher
backend https_server005
        mode tcp
        server server005 $BK_SERVER_002:9443
#reports
backend https_server006
        mode tcp 
        server server006 $BK_SERVER_001:4443 
#sonar
backend https_server007
        mode http
        server server007 $BK_SERVER_001:9000
```

For OPTION 2, HAProxy successfully publish the service "sonar" using the given certificate, however, the rest of services are trying to use that certificate.
Since the other services are already SSL enabled in their corresponding backends, I do NOT have their certificates.

If I use OPTION 1, HAProxy successfully publish all the already-ssl-backend services except "sonar" service, because it needs a certificate that I have only at the proxy_server level.

Is it possible to have all the services secured with SSL if (like I said) some of them are already secured but some others will be secured by the HAProxy with the only one SSL that I have access for "sonar" service? How?

Please also note that I do not have ssh access to the $BK_SERVER_xxx servers and that I have all the DNS pointing their names to "proxy_server".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to achieve what you're trying to do: As you've seen, once you present a certificate the listener stops "blindly" proxying encrypted traffic straight to the correct backend, and instead tries to terminate all client TLS connections using the certificate(s) provided, failing if it can't provide a valid one for the domain requested.

The way I see it you have a couple of simple alternatives:
1. Set up a separate reverse proxy in front of "sonar" and any future services where you do own the certificate.
2. Purchase a wildcard certificate for *.ci.example.edu to use in the frontend, and point out a CA certificate to allow HAProxy to validate the certificates presented by the backend servers.

Edited to add: HAProxy happily lets you define multiple listener certificates, so you can easily listen to requests for multiple domains using a single frontend as long as the clients understand how to select among the certificates presented - which all modern and standards-compliant software does.